# Express.js 4.0 -- use separate view directory for each router

Tags: node.js, express, view, express-4

I'm using Express 4 [routers](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router) to separate out two different app functions.  Each app function has its own set of ejs view templates, with conflicting names (e.g both have a `search.ejs`).

How can I specify the router to use only a particular view directory to render views?  For example, the view directory would look like this:

```
views/
   app1/
      - search.ejs
      - index.ejs
   app2/
      - search.ejs
      - index.ejs
```